# refactor suggestion for my array iteration?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

i feel like there is a more elegant way what i have done below.. Any suggestion ?

```
import Foundation

var bullet = ["aka","bz","cy"]

for i in bullet {
    if i.contains("ka") {
        let p = bullet.firstIndex(of: i)
        bullet[p!]
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a `contains` check if you're using `firstIndex(of:)`. Just conditionally unwrap that, instead of force unwrapping it as you are

Comment: Please add the desired output to the question?

Comment: if my array contains ka for any value i print my label that value aka if not i print asdfgj for example so i need to find where it is which index

Comment: What if there are multiple values that contain "ka" in your array?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the first matching value, then you can use `first`, if you want to get it's index then, you can use `firstIndex` and `if let` is to safely unwrap an optional value.

```
var bullet = ["aka","bz","cy"]


if let value = bullet.first(where: { $0.contains("ka") }) {
    print(value) //"aka"
}

if let index = bullet.firstIndex(where: { $0.contains("ka")}) {
    print(index) //0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`filter(_:)`** along with **`contains(_:)`** like,

```
let arr = bullet.filter { $0.contains("ka") }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if let kaItem = bullet.first({ $0.contains(“ka”) }) {
    myLabel.text = kaItem
} else {
    myLabel.text = “asdfghj”
}
```

If you need to get the index and set the text, you can use firstIndex method:

```
   if let kaItemIndex = bullet.firstIndex({ $0.contains(“ka”) }) {
        myLabel.text = bullet[kaItemIndex]
    } else {
        myLabel.text = “asdfghj”
    }
```